# Eximee - how to export an artifact from Eximee repository?

Tags: forms

how to export an artifact from Eximee repository in a specific version 2.11?

this way doesn't work:
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --fail --user eximee -X GET http://eximee-repository:8080/repository/migration/form_name/2/11/export -o form_name.artifact && echo "OK"

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use legacy stand-alone eximee Designer and choose "Export artifact" from context menu: [artifact context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiUR0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your url is incorrect
http://eximee-repository:8080/repository/migration/form_name/**2.11**/export